# Using Prescaler above 64 on ATTiny45

Tags: arduino, timer, attiny

I'm trying to setup Timer0 on an ATTiny45 using the arduino-tiny core. TIM0_COMPA_vect works fine for prescalers 1,8 and 64, but 256 and 1024 cause the ISR to not fire. I am running the chip at 1MHz.

Setup code is as follows:

```
void setup()
{
  ADCSRA &= ~(1<<ADEN); //Disable ADC
  ACSR = (1<<ACD); //Disable the analog comparator
  DIDR0 = 0x3F; //Disable digital input buffers on all ADC0-ADC5 pins.

  DDRB |= _BV(PINB0); // Set Pin 5 (PB0) as output;
  PORTB &= ~_BV(PINB0); //Set it to low, just to be safe

  //cli();
  TCCR0A |= _BV(WGM01); //CTC Mode
  TCCR0B |= (_BV(CS02) | _BV(CS00)); //Prescale 1024
  TIMSK  |= _BV(OCIE0A); //enable CTC interrupt
  OCR0A = 243; 

  sei();
}
```

fuses are:

```
low_fuses=0x62
high_fuses=0xD7
extended_fuses=0xFF
```

Any thoughts on why this might be the case?

**Update:** Not only do prescalers /256 and /1024 not work for COMPA or COMPB but they do not work for the overflow ISR either.  I don't really get it since according to table 11-6 in the [ATTinyx5 datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-2586-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny25-ATtiny45-ATtiny85_Datasheet.pdf), it supports prescalers /1, /8, /64, /256, and /1024 via the TCCR0B register.

Comment: One thing to check is that the watchdog is definitively turned off, or longer delays will result in watchdog timeouts instead! Does a short delay (OCR0A=small) work with higher prescale settings?

Comment: Hmmm... will check tonight on the small OCR0A. But how do you turn off the watchdog?

Comment: No joy... tried both setting OCR0A to 1 and wdt_disable(); to turn of the WDT. Still nothing when using /256 or /1024

Comment: BTW... the overflow ISR doesn't work either when using /256 or /1024

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect the Arduino startup code is setting the timer registers, especially `TCCR0B`  to a value other than the startup default of zero. Try the following code that removes the OR:

```
TCCR0B = (_BV(CS02) | _BV(CS00)); //Prescale 1024
```

Looking at the datasheet / 256 and /1024 both have `CS02` set to one. If `CS01` is set to one by the Arduino code that will be enabling the external clock source when you're trying to set the higher divisor values.

The only other thing worth pointing out is that Arduino tends to use `TIMER0` for functions like delay() and millis(). Once you've changed the timer setup those functions won't operate as per usual so you might need to write your own timing routines if required.

Comment: Correct you are! Worked like a charm. Guess the |= was just habit. A habit I should break.